# Shared Pointer set in Lambda after out of scope

Tags: c++, lambda, scope, shared-ptr

I am having a problem with shared pointers, lambdas and scope.

My situation is that I have a method which I call, so I can use later the returned value. Kind of normal until here. The problem comes when I have an async method inside this method, that I have to make a set of an exception to a shared_pointer. I am using a lambda function to process the callback from this async method. In this lambda I have to use my shared_pointer and set an exception on it (a method from its class) resultPtr->setException();

I first used a shared_ptr, then a weak_ptr in the lambda (because I read in some places that the shared_ptr could lead to memory leaks). But until now I guess I really need to use a shared_ptr.

I have to test if this exception is being set in a second .cpp, so I call the method and use the returned value. I put the thread waiting for about 500ms then I test if it has exceptions, but it does not. However, in very rare cases, it "hasException". I can see that the lambda is being called and that it sets the exception through my logs, however it seems like it does not change the value I returned first (like it is pointing to a different place).

The inputs of the first method I mentioned are not important for my case, only that they are Pointers.

In my case I have something like:

```
file1.cpp
typedef shared_ptr<Result> ResultPtr;
ResultPtr method_name(TypePtr args)
{
    if(args != nullptr)
    {
        ResultPtr result = make_shared<Result>();
        stuff->callAsync([this, result](input)
        {
            if(result == nullptr)
            {
                result->setException();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        result->setError();
    }
    return result;
}

file2.cpp
bool testingMethod()
{
    ResultPtr result = file1::methodName(TypePtr args)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    test(result->hasException);
}
```

For testing I am using another class where I call this method with certain inputs(not important here) and I need to compare the object value of resultPtr. What happens is that as soon as it goes out of scope (return a), I can't access the object anymore. After I call this method, I put the thread waiting for about 1 second, but it never changes the state (since it can't point to a destroyed object)

Is there anyway to overcome this? Other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `stuff`?

Comment: "What happens is that as soon as it goes out of scope (return a), I can't access the object anymore." this is not true so it is unclear what problem you have. Provide [mcve]

Comment: Your example is confusing in many ways. Narrow it down to things that are relevant to your problem. You have "args" without type and no usage anywhere, "method_name" being a member function, but there's no class, "input" without type....

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If not being able to compile is the problem "return a;", narrow it down to the line that does not compile.

Comment: @JonathanMee Some irrelevant code for this scenario. could be just some log or nothing at all, so I decided to keep it out.

Comment: @lars I understand. I actually spent too many hours on this and my brain is confused itself. I tried to get things that I thought to be unnecessary as abstract. The args are not important here, just to show that I am setting an exception if args is/are nullptrs. 
everything compiles well, and there are no crashes. Check my edit, maybe it helps understanding better my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can't access the object anymore, because it is [destroyed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr) when the [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) leaves the scope of the `if(args)` block, where it is created. You'll need to have the object living outside the method, e. g. storing it as class member or (<deity> forbid!) in a global variable.

Whether you need to wrap it in a shared pointer or not is unclear, you'll need to provide a MCVE together with a clearer description of [what you want to achieve](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 2):

If you need the lambda to guarantee that it keeps the object alive, why are you using a weak pointer to pass in, instead of a shared pointer? The purpose of a weak pointer is the behaviour you are seeing, where it does not itself keep the object alive.

Because you are only capturing a weak pointer it does not keep the shared pointer alive when the only shared pointer goes out of scope, if it goes out of scope before you have locked the weak pointer. But you could just capture the shared pointer (by value, so a copy is taken) instead of using a weak pointer. Then the reference count will be incremented and the shared pointer inside the lambda will keep it alive, and it will only be deleted when both shared pointers have gone out of scope.

Shared ownership like this is the reason for a shared pointer, you should only use a weak pointer if it is desirable that the object will no longer be accessible if the shared pointer reference count reaches zero.

Comment: Yes I am aware of it now, but I was not sure if I was thinking correctly. The original code had shared_pointers passed to lambda. After your answer I decided to just keep the shared_ptr in my solution. However that way it still does not solve my problem. When I am using the returned value from that method, then the lambda receives the callback. But this value does not update the value I received in this other method that I am using for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If your `callAsync` is really asynchronous, your lambda could start to execute when local variables `result` and `a` is alreay out of scope. You should pass needed variables as parameters, e.g. as binding with `std::bind`:

```
typedef shared_ptr<Result> ResultPtr;
ResultPtr method_name(args)
{
    if(args)
    {
        ResultPtr a = make_shared<Result>();
        std::weak_ptr<Result> result(a);
        stuff->callAsync(std::bind([this](std::weak_ptr<Result> result_param)
        {
            auto resultPtr = result_param.lock();
            if(resultPtr)
            {
                resultPtr->setValue()
                ...other stuff...
            }
        }, result));
    }
    else
    {
        a->setError();
    }
    return a;
}
```

and yes, your example is confusing

Comment: The method is async. I just provide the arguments for it and I received later a callback with what I need (this async Method is not implemented by me, neither I can change it). So I guess the bind would not work here. My problem is that I need to change a value of a shared_ptr in a lambda, but I am returning it before the lambda is executing. When I am trying to use the returned value in another class (I am testing it), even though the lambda executes and sets the value to the correct thing, it seems like it not update the pointer I am using in the second class.